# PHP dynamic image gallery - Fetching S3Bucket images as array - not displaying images

Tags: php, amazon-s3, gallery

I am fetching images dynamically from S3 Bucket based on filename and trying to display the same on a webpage.  The code populates the array of URL's perfectly.  However, when I build the html in php by providing the img src as url using foreach function, the images are not getting displayed.

The following is the code:

```
$objects = json_decode(exec($pyexec) , true);
//echo gettype($objects);


foreach ($objects as $object) {
  $num = $s3->getObjectUrl(BUCKET, $object);
  //echo $num;
  $imgname = basename($num);

   echo '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 ">';
    echo '<img src="'.$num.'" id="thumbNails'.$imgname.'" width="200" height="200" class="img" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail" /></div>';
}
```

In this the `gettype($objects)` prints that it is a array.  When I use `print_r($objects)` it prints the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1205944447_1544090338.044875.jpg
    [1] => 1205944447_1544090338.456757.jpg
    [2] => 1205944447_1544090338.870485.jpg
    [3] => 1205944447_1544090340.111561.jpg
)
```

From within the foreach when I echo the urls I get the following:

```
https://myawsbuck123.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/1205944447_1544090338.044875.jpghttps://myawsbuck123.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/1205944447_1544090338.456757.jpghttps://myawsbuck123.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/1205944447_1544090338.870485.jpghttps://myawsbuck123.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/1205944447_1544090340.111561.jpg
```

Instead of populating the foreach function on a webpage, when I run it from console, I get the following output:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 "><img src="https://myawsbuck123.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/1205944447_1544090338.044875.jpg" id="thumbNails1205944447_1544090338.044875.jpg" width="200" height="200" class="img" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail" /></div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 "><img src="https://myawsbuck123.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/1205944447_1544090338.456757.jpg" id="thumbNails1205944447_1544090338.456757.jpg" width="200" height="200" class="img" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail" /></div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 "><img src="https://myawsbuck123.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/1205944447_1544090338.870485.jpg" id="thumbNails1205944447_1544090338.870485.jpg" width="200" height="200" class="img" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail" /></div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 "><img src="https://myawsbuck123.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/1205944447_1544090340.111561.jpg" id="thumbNails1205944447_1544090340.111561.jpg" width="200" height="200" class="img" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail" /></div>
```

To me they all look ok. Not sure why it is images could not be seen on the webpage. I have check the permission of S3 Bucket - they have public access enabled for both the bucket as well as the images in the bucket. However, when I try to populate the images from a local directory similar code executes without trouble.  How do I get to display the images from the S3 bucket and is my URL correct?

Edit:
I am using python to query dynamodb table to get the names of the images and then trying to fetch the images urls based on the image and bucket name.  When I just dump the `print_r($objects)` there are no errors.  However, When I using PHP to produce the gallery, I get the following boto3 & php error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filterImages.py", line 2, in <module>
    import boto3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from boto3.session import Session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/session.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
ImportError: No module named botocore.session
[Fri Dec 07 11:00:51.507209 2018] [:error] [pid 6767] [client ::1:64844] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/getImages.php on line 48, referer: http://localhost/images.php
```

Comment: Do you able to access the image directly via browser?

Comment: @Vamsi  Yes I can